# How to save a picture from a website that keeps calling itself?

Tags: html, shell, sockets

I want to save the picture that appears at this address: http://yunogo.miemasu.net/nphMotionJpeg?resolution=640x480. 
Following is the source code of the page:

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>nphMotionJpeg 640×480 pixels</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px">
    <img style="-webkit-user-select:none; display:block; margin:auto;" src="http://yunogo.miemasu.net/nphMotionJpeg?resolution=640x480">
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the issue is that the image object calls itself to update so which ever script or language I use it gets stuck on the line that is receiving objects from the mentioned url.
I have tried webkit2png, wget,urllib but they have not proved useful.

Possible Ideas:

Write a high level script to open up the link in browser, maximise it, take a snapshot of the screen, crop out the area with image, save it.

Write a script to make a call to the page break it in between, fetch temp objects from cache.

Note: The objective is to get the image from the page, it can be any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam):

```
ffmpeg -i "http://yunogo.miemasu.net/nphMotionJpeg?resolution=640x480" out_%03d.jpg
```

In this case, the `out_%03d.jpg` will save the image like:

```
out_001.jpg
out_002.jpg
out_003.jpg
...
```

To get only one picture, a [single frame](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video):

```
ffmpeg -i "http://yunogo.miemasu.net/nphMotionJpeg?resolution=640x480" -vframes 1 out.jpg
```

You could force the input by defining `-f mjpeg`, but normally the format is auto detected:

```
ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i "http://yunogo.miemasu.net/nphMotionJpeg?resolution=640x480" -vframes 1 out.jpg
```